# Ant Sync task with zipfileset

Tags: ant, synchronization, zip

I'm attempting to synchronize the contents in a zip file with a folder on my system using the ant sync task.

I have the task:

```
<target name="test-zipfiletest">
  <sync todir="dest">
    <zipfileset src="test.zip"/>
  </sync>
</target>
```

when i run it things are fine the contents make it to the folder

```
test-zipfiletest:
[sync] Copying 1 resource to C:\_dev\ide\springsource\workspaces\workspace_builds\install_utils\dest
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 184 milliseconds
```

Ok that's great.

BUT... now if i run the task again it deletes the contents:

```
test-zipfiletest:
 [sync] Removed 3 dangling directories from C:\_dev\ide\springsource\workspaces\workspace_builds\install_utils\dest
 [sync] Removed 1 dangling file from C:\_dev\ide\springsource\workspaces\workspace_builds\install_utils\dest
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 148 milliseconds
```

I would have expected no change and nothing would have been synchronized....
Anyone come across this? Or know how to get this to work properly?
thanks,
Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the issue - looks like a problem with ant

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51462